# If each item in a Pandas data frame column is an array, is there a function to parse through the list to find a maximum value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I have the data frame, new_df, in which I would like to parse through each item in the 'Ages' column, which is an array of strings.

```
df = train_cases[train_cases['Family_name'].duplicated(keep = False)]
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Ages' : df.groupby(df['Family_name'])['Age'].transform(lambda x: '| '.join(x.astype(str))),
                       'Names' : df.groupby(df['Family_name'])['Name'].transform(lambda x: '| '.join(x)),
                       'Family_name' : df['Family_name']
                        })

new_df['Ages'] = new_df['Ages'].apply(lambda x: x.split('| ')) 
new_df['Names'] = new_df['Names'].apply(lambda x: x.split('| '))

new_df.head(10)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to convert each list element into an integer or float and  parse through each list in the 'Ages' column to get the maximum value.

train_cases is a data frame which I made by reading a .csv file from the Kaggle Titanic competition, with the following code:

```py
def fam_name(name):
    return name.split(',')[0]

train_cases = pd.read_csv("/.../train.csv")
train_cases = train_cases.dropna(subset = ['PassengerId','Pclass','Sex','Age','SibSp','Parch','Fare'],how = "any")
train_cases['Family_name'] = train_cases['Name'].apply(lambda x: fam_name(x))
```

I have tried the following algorithm:

```
max_val = 0

for x in new_df['Ages']:
    for ind, y in enumerate(x):
        if float(y) > max_val:
            
            max_val = float(y)
            max_index = ind
            
            print(max_val, max_index)
```

But it doesn't seem to return the proper values.

Comment: please provide a reproducible piece of code to help you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use [df.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to create a more useable dataframe first, then return the age of the oldest person in each family. By not setting `ignore_index=True` within `explode()` this answer will also return the original index of the family name.

```
new_df.explode(['Ages', 'Names']).groupby('Family_name')['Ages'].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["1","2","3", "1"],"b":[[1,3],[5,16],[25,33,34], [45]]})
#
   a             b
0  1        [1, 3]
1  2       [5, 16]
2  3  [25, 33, 34]
3  1          [45]
#
grouped_df = df.groupby("a", as_index=False)["b"].sum()
grouped_df["c"] = grouped_df["b"].apply(max)
grouped_df
   a             b   c
0  1    [1, 3, 45]  45
1  2       [5, 16]  16
2  3  [25, 33, 34]  34
```

I am not sure that this answers your question in full, but it should be help.